# Get time between reaching target (above) and exiting target (below) on chart

Tags: c#, winforms, plc

The following chart updates its values using a winforms Timer every second. The red line represents a constant target testing pressure, the blue line is the actual pressure read from a PLC object.

[Y Axis  = Testing Pressure, X Axis = Current Time, chart is updated with winforms timer at Interval = 1000 (every second)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1z5o.png)

The requirement is showing how many seconds have passed between the blue line reaching the constant required testing pressure (red line) and falling below the
constant required testing pressure.

The block that sets the constant required testing pressure:

```
...
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Position = d;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineWidth = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

The part where I am stuck (this block is inside the method which updates the chart every second):

```
                                                                        double plcTestpressure = ((uint)plc.Read("MD220")).ConvertToDouble();
                    double reqTestPressure = Convert.ToDouble(txtTestingPressure.Text);

                    if (plcTestpressure > reqTestPressure && !isAboveReq)
                    {
                        DateTime aboveReq = new DateTime();
                        aboveReq = DateTime.Now;
                        isAboveReq = true;
                        //this is for checking the plc read pressure
                        string currentpressure = ((uint)plc.Read("MD220")).ConvertToDouble().ToString();
                    }
                    //check if current pressure is below required and that pressure WAS above required a second ago...
                    if(plcTestpressure < reqTestPressure && isAboveReq)
                    {
                        DateTime belowReq = new DateTime();
                        belowReq = DateTime.Now;                    
                        tickCounter = (belowReq - aboveReq).TotalSeconds;
                        isAboveReq = false;
                    }
```

I have tried and stepped through this block, but it gives me a misleading answer in tickCounter (33 seconds when you can visually see on the graph 5 seconds have passed) and after the first time the tickCounter is assigned to, the aboveReq datetime stamp does not want to change.

Is there a better way to accomplish this goal? Am I going about it wrong? Should I provide more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to assume you have multiple variables named "aboveReq" since variables declared in an "if" block are local to the block. That means that when you access the "aboveReq" variable in the second "if" block, you aren't accessing the same variable.

Also does `string currentpressure = ((uint)plc.Read("MD220")).ConvertToDouble().ToString();` really need to be within the if block (only tracking current pressure while above target)?

```
//Outside of method, top of class
private DateTime? _startTime = null;
private DateTime? _endTime = null;

//In method
 string currentpressure = ((uint)plc.Read("MD220")).ConvertToDouble().ToString();

 bool breachPressure = plcTestpressure > reqTestPressure;

 if (breachPressure && _startTime == null)
 {
    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
 }
 else if(!breachPressure && _startTime != null)
 {
    _endTime = new DateTime();
    var tickCounter = _endTime.Value.Subtract(_startTime.Value).TotalSeconds;
 }
```

-----------------------------Edit---------------------------------------

> Am I going about it wrong?

It would be considered cleaner if you moved the pressure monitoring logic to a separate class, thus keeping true to the single responsibility principle.

You can do that by implementing a pressure monitoring class that would raise events when the threshold is breached - something along the lines of -

```
        public class PressureObserver
        {
            public event EventHandler<double> OnRaisedAboveThreshhold;
            public event EventHandler<double> OnFellBelowThreshhold;

            public double ThresholdPressure{ get; }

            private double _lastMeasured = 0; //Initial Pressure

            public PressureObserver(double thresholdPressure)
            {
                ThresholdPressure = thresholdPressure;
            }

            public void Observe(double plcTestpressure)
            {
                double pressureDelta = plcTestpressure - _lastMeasured;

                if (pressureDelta > 0) //Pressure climbed
                {
                    if(_lastMeasured < ThresholdPressure &&  //Last measurement was below threshold
                        plcTestpressure > ThresholdPressure) //This one is above, cross made
                    {
                        OnRaisedAboveThreshhold?.Invoke(this, plcTestpressure);
                    }
                }
                else if(pressureDelta < 0) //Pressure declined
                {
                    if (_lastMeasured > ThresholdPressure &&  //Last measurement was above threshold
                        plcTestpressure < ThresholdPressure) //This one is below, cross made
                    {
                        OnFellBelowThreshhold?.Invoke(this, plcTestpressure);
                    }
                }

                _lastMeasured = plcTestpressure;
            }
        }
```

Then in your main class you would have fields

```
        private PressureObserver _pressureObserver;
        private DateTime _raisedAboveTime;
        private DateTime _fellBelowTime;
        private double _overpressureDuration;
```

you would define two methods to react to threshold changes

```
        private void Obs_OnRaisedAboveTreshhold(object sender, double e)
        {
            //Code to do on raised above
            _raisedAboveTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void Obs_OnFellBelowTreshhold(object sender, double e)
        {
            //Code to do on fell below
            _fellBelowTime = DateTime.Now;
            _overpressureDuration = _fellBelowTime.Subtract(_raisedAboveTime).TotalSeconds;
        }
```

and in the constructor you would subscribe to the observer class

```
       _pressureObserver = new PressureObserver(60); //replace 60 with threshold

       _pressureObserver.OnRaisedAboveThreshhold += Obs_OnRaisedAboveTreshhold;
       _pressureObserver.OnFellBelowThreshhold += Obs_OnFellBelowTreshhold;
```

and in your tick timer you would just add

```
_pressureObserver.Observe(plcTestpressure);
```

Comment: "variables declared in an "if" block are local to the block", great, can't believe I missed that. That clears my confusion on that end.